# Prevent PhpStorm from opening new instance of Firefox browser

Tags: php, firefox, phpstorm

I used to use <kbd>Shift + F1</kbd> shortcut in order to view official PHP documentation for functions (place caret on function name and press <kbd>Shift + F1</kbd>). PhpStorm used to open documentation in new tab of existing browser window (it is expected behavior for me). However recently for some reason it stopped working this way.

Is there way to make PhpStorm open new browser tab instead of new browser window?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that I had to set such PhpStorm configuration in order to make it work:

- Default browser: First Listed (instead of System default);
- Firefox Profile: default-release (instead of default).

[image]